# Using Go's HTTP server for production

Tags: go

I'm a PHP developer new to Golang. PHP comes with an inbuilt server which is not recommended for production. I read the [beautiful book by astaxie](http://astaxie.gitbooks.io/build-web-application-with-golang/) on web development in Go and also the [golang.org example on writing a web app](http://golang.org/doc/articles/wiki/). They both use the `http.ListenAndServe()` to create a web server. I just want to know if this server can be used in production or is it just a dummy server like PHP inbuilt server? By production I mean, can it handle huge traffic like an Apache or ngnix server?

Comment: OP asked "I just want to know if this server can be used in production or is it just a dummy server". This is not so much opinion based IMO, it's a focused question with a definite answer (yes), but not a straightforward programming question as well, I'll admit.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Short answer: YES.

Longer answer: you can certainly use the built in Web server for production traffic. There's a good chance you've used it today, since Google serves some traffic using it. I know a lot of companies, including the one I work for that use it for production traffic. BTW I don't know of a Web server widely used in Go that does *not* use the standard web server.

Keep in mind though that you need to tweak things like client timeouts to make it really robust, and perhaps limit incoming connections, etc.

Comment: is it the google URL shortener that they use Go server in ?

Comment: @AkashKumarSharma No idea. One thing I do know that runs on it is their download servers. See here, this is a great talk https://talks.golang.org/2013/oscon-dl.slide#1

Answer (score 7):

To add to @Not_a_Golfer's answer: Go's web-server is extremely solid and pretty well tested thus far.

There are, however, reasons why you might put it behind a reverse proxy like nginx, Apache or HAProxy, including:

- SSL termination (nginx has a lot of additional TLS features that you'll have to partially implement yourself, like easy OCSP stapling support)
- Proxy caching (serving static responses from cache, or 500 if your Go app crashes)
- Performant logging
- SPDY support (although both Go & nginx will probably get HTTP/2 at the same time)
- Built-in gzip support and options
- File descriptor caching for static files

I *generally* prefer to put nginx in front if I have the option, because although you can implement all of those features in Go, there's a bit of wheel re-invention going on. You can get most of the way there with middleware like [gorilla/handlers](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/handlers) and Go's own crypto/tls lib, and if you're not an ops person and/or want to keep things really thin, then running everything directly from Go is still fine for production.

Comment: I plan to use nginx mainly for proxy caching now that it feels that Go server is a hefty performer itself.